# Cannot find name 'abort' during npm run build

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, thegraph

/node_modules/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/chain/ethereum.ts:47:7

```
export class Value {
    constructor(public kind: ValueKind, public data: ValuePayload) {}

    @operator('<')
    lt(_: Value): boolean {
      abort("Less than operator isn't supported in Value");
      return false;
    }
```

When trying the `npm run build` command for the node typescript project, I am getting the above error. I am using The Graph por blockchain queries.

I already tried to install codegen on the main, and subgraph folders. Also, added this plugins to mi `subgraph.yaml`:

```
graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-resolvers"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
      - "typescript-operations"
```